# c++ try/catch ignorance in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, compiler-errors, xcode7, rapidjson

In our app we have a c++ static library and I use Objective-C++ to work with it.
That c++ library utilizes rapidjson to parse XML data:

```
try {
            rapidjson::Document document;
            document.Parse(connection.data.description);
            connection.openTime = document["openFrom"].GetInt();
            connection.closeTime = document["openTo"].GetInt();
            return true;
        } catch (std::exception e) {
            connection.openTime = 0;
            connection.closeTime = 0;
            return false;
        }
```

The problem is that if document["openFrom"] cannot be converted into Int via GetInt() method, exception is not raised. Instead of that my app crashes with SIGABRT.

```
Assertion failed: (data_.f.flags & kIntFlag), function GetInt, file /Users/xxx/xxx/xx/ios/../src/rapidjson/document.h, line 1645.
```

On Android OS, btw, in the same case exception is raised successfully.
What could be the problem? I guess the issue is in Xcode's Swift compiler behavior.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `catch (const std::exception& e)`?  Also are you sure `GetInt()` returns something that is derived from `std::exception`?

Comment: @NathanOliver that was the first thing I tried to do, didn't help. I'm not good at c++ at all, just wondered the same thing: how is it possible that in such situation (when GetInt() cannot convert input-text into Integer) the exception won't be raised. And how it depends on compilers/OS (as on Android OS, exception was raise and catch block took action)

Answer (score 2):

As it clearly stated in the log you provided – it is not a *crash*, it is only a failed assert which internally calls `abort()` that results in `SIGABRT` which stands for 'signal abort'. Asserts are disabled in release mode so it should work fine there. Or you can disable asserts in rapidjson (by defining macro `RAPIDJSON_ASSERT`).

Comment: Looks like a solution. The is issue that somehow they are not disabled in release mode (which is set in Scheme settings->Archive->Buid config). Anyway I'll try to disable them inside of rapidjson, tnx!